# Best practices for efficiently storing md5 hashes in MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, database-design, md5, nosql

Assuming we have an md5 hash:

With ruby:

```
>Digest::MD5.hexdigest("ZZtop")
=> "d3e5c7c22df12b70e882f593432a3bdd"
```

Possible field types:

> :type => String
>
> :type => Hash

Which should I choose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a String. A Hash in BSON refers to a key-value pair set.

Answer (score 4):

In MongoDB, hash does **not** mean a cryptographic fingerprint (as in MD5 or SHA-1). It means hash as in hash table (a data structure that allows the storage of key-value pairs).

You have to use a string to store a MD5 fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

String, or better yet is to use Binary, its about half the size.

```
> Digest::MD5.hexdigest("ZZtop").size
=> 32
> Digest::MD5.digest("ZZtop").size
=> 16
```

You may have to get around the [UTF8 check](http://api.mongodb.org/perl/current/MongoDB/DataTypes.html#Binary%20Data) by explicitly telling stating its BSON::Binary.

```
> BSON::Binary.new(Digest::MD5.digest("ZZtop"))
```