# Using an MD5 Hash as an index

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, hash, nosql

I am writing a MongoDB Collection that contains a specific set of data, and I want to run comparisons against that data by taking an MD5 (or maybe SHA256) hash of the data and basing comparisons off of that.

I was wondering if using a fixed-length character string of hex-numbers is the right way of doing this. Is there a better datatype to use, such as a "blob" or even a 64bit long integer to hold the values? (This may require me to use a hashing function that produces longs -- I don't know of one except maybe overriding the Java .hashCode() function with Eclispe?)

If there is a better way entirely, advise on best practice would be appreciated here!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are basically looking for a proper hash function for elements of a collection?

Comment: Yes -- and once that hash function is found, the best datatype to use in Mongo to hold the hash. Since a hash is made up of just 0-9A-F, I think a string would be excessive?

Comment: I depends on what you want to use this for really. Just dumping binary content to MongoDB is very simple as it just does it and exact comparisons are not a problem either. If you didn't expect this to be completely random and required some sort of ordering, then you would be better off with a string. I presume that the purpose of this is to match content in a "sub-set" of fields, otherwise there would be no point at all. For a whole document of uniquely hashed content is called a "primary-key", which already exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Storing MD5 Hashes in MongoDB**

You have to use String or Binary (half the size) in case you decide to store a MD5 hash (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991447/best-practices-for-efficiently-storing-md5-hashes-in-mongodb)).

**Best Hash Function**

This is tough to answer, since it highly depends on the kind of data in your collection. I personally think that MD5 hashes are a good way, but again it depends on the use-case. In case you want to customize/optimize your hash, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738886/what-is-a-best-practice-of-writing-hash-function-in-java) might get you started. They cover some simple recipes on writing a custom hash function.